# Dominant projections and degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to prove the following result: Let $X\subset \mathbb{C}^m$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{C}^{n}$ be irreducible varieties of the same dimension, with $m\geq n$. Let $\pi\colon\mathbb{C}^m\to\mathbb{C}^n$ be a projection (for example, the projection onto the first $n$ coordinates). Suppose that $\pi\colon X\to Y$ is dominant and that the fiber above a generic point of $\pi$ has cardinality 1. Then $X$ and $Y$ have the same degree.

I know that the fields $K(X)$ and $K(Y)$ are isomorphic, but this doesn't seem to be enough to show that the two varieties have the same degree. Does anyone have thoughts on how to prove this?

Comment: Varieties in $ \mathbb C^n$ don't have a degree.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg , To clarify, we could define the degree of an irreducible variety $Y\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ to be the cardinality of $Y\cap H$, where $H$ is a generic linear space of codimension $\operatorname{dim}(Y)$.